# Scrapy - authenticated to google services

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a complete Python newbie but I would need to scrape a specific page in google analytics, Google has as [split sign-in process](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/05/15/google-splits-sign-in-process-into-two-pages/) in two pages and I don't know how to make it work with scrapy's FormRequest.

I have  tried to login to login to gmail as a test with the following code :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'super'
start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=fr#identifier']

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'Email': 'email@example.com', 'Passwd': 'password example'},

                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
  if "authentication failed" in response.body:
    self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
    return
# We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
  else:
    return Request(url="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox",
           callback=self.parse_tastypage)


def parse_tastypage(self, response):
  sel = Selector(response)
  item = Item()
  item ["Test"] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
  yield item
```

but It didn't work, here is my log file:

```
2016-03-27 10:30:19 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-03-27 10:30:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 

items (at 0 items/min)
2016-03-27 10:30:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 148.0.0.1:6023
2016-03-27 10:30:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=fr#identifier> (referer: None)
2016-03-27 10:30:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=fr)
2016-03-27 10:30:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1> from <GET https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox>
2016-03-27 10:30:30 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo)
2016-03-27 10:30:30 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/machine/super/super/spiders/mySuper.py", line 26, in parse_tastypage
    sel = Selector(response)
NameError: global name 'Selector' is not defined
2016-03-27 10:30:30 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-03-27 10:30:30 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1874,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 197446,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 27, 14, 30, 30, 741077),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'spider_exceptions/NameError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 27, 14, 30, 19, 82107)}
2016-03-27 10:30:30 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

An idea on how I should proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing imports so your code errors, you have not imported Selector nor Item:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Item
```

If you look at the output you can clearly see:

```
 NameError: global name 'Selector' is not defined
```

You would see the exact same for Item if you did not also import that.

You also have  `level=log.ERROR` where log is not defined or imported anywhere, you probably want *logging.ERROR* so you need to import logging:

```
 import logging


 level=logging.ERROR
```

This is all pretty basic stuff, I would suggest you go through a  [tutorial](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/) before you attempt to go anywhere near classes or any kind of complex code, if you son't understand the basics well then life is going to be harder than it needs to be.

This is a working implementation:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import  Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import  logging
from scrapy import Field
from scrapy import Item


class Product(Item):
    Test =  Field()


class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'super'
    start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=fr#identifier']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'Email': 'foo@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'pass'},

                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
        return
    # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
    print("Login Successful!!")
    return Request(url="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox",
               callback=self.parse_tastypage)


    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
      item = Product()
      item ["Test"] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
      yield item
```

A sample run using my login:

```
 DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=fr)
Login Successful!!
2016-03-28 02:13:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1> from <GET https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox>
```

I have not verified that it actually works, I just used you own logic, regardless, it is a working example of how to use scrapy.

Comment: Thanks Padraic your code helped a lot! I can now login to google analytics but I'm stuck again, I can't seem to be able to send the required http request to get the data that I need. I have posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273347/scraping-google-analytics-with-scrapy

Comment: No worries, I am about to quit for the night but will have a look in the a.m if you don't get an answer before then.