# Scraping Google Analytics by Scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to use Scrapy to get some data from Google Analytics and despite the fact that I'm a complete Python newbie I have made some progress. 
I can now login to Google Analytics by Scrapy but I need to make an AJAX request to get the data what I want. I have tried to replicate my browser's HTTP request header with the code below but it doesn't seem to work, my error log says

> too many values to unpack

Could somebody help? I've been worked on it for two days, I have the feeling that I'm very close but I'm also very confused.

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import  logging
from super.items import SuperItem
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
import json

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'super'
    start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=analytics&passive=true&nui=1&hl=fr&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr#identifier']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'Email': 'Email'},

                    callback=self.log_password)]


    def log_password(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'Passwd': 'Password'},

                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
        return
    # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
      else:
        print("Login Successful!!")
        return Request(url="https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/getPage?id=trafficsources-all-traffic&ds=a5425w87291514p94531107&hl=fr&authuser=0",
               method='POST',
               headers=[{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
                         'Galaxy-Ajax': 'true',
                         'Origin': 'https://analytics.google.com',
                         'Referer': 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr&pli=1',
                         'User-Agent': 'My-user-agent',
                         'X-GAFE4-XSRF-TOKEN': 'Mytoken'}],
               callback=self.parse_tastypage, dont_filter=True)


    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
        response = json.loads(jsonResponse)

        inspect_response(response, self)
        yield item
```

And here is part of the log:

```
2016-03-28 19:11:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-03-28 19:11:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-03-28 19:11:39 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-03-28 19:11:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-03-28 19:11:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=analytics&passive=true&nui=1&hl=fr&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr#identifier> (referer: None)
2016-03-28 19:11:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=analytics&passive=true&nui=1&hl=fr&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr)
2016-03-28 19:11:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?hl=fr&checkedDomains=youtube&pstMsg=0&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&service=analytics&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&gidl=CAA> from <POST https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth>
2016-03-28 19:11:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr> from <GET https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?hl=fr&checkedDomains=youtube&pstMsg=0&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&service=analytics&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&gidl=CAA>
2016-03-28 19:12:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo)
Login Successful!!
2016-03-28 19:12:01 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/aminbouraiss/super/super/spiders/mySuper.py", line 42, in after_login
    callback=self.parse_tastypage, dont_filter=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.headers = Headers(headers or {}, encoding=encoding)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/http/headers.py", line 12, in __init__
    super(Headers, self).__init__(seq)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/datatypes.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.update(seq)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/datatypes.py", line 229, in update
    super(CaselessDict, self).update(iseq)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/datatypes.py", line 228, in <genexpr>
    iseq = ((self.normkey(k), self.normvalue(v)) for k, v in seq)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
2016-03-28 19:12:01 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-03-28 19:12:01 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 6419,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 75986,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 28, 23, 12, 1, 824033),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
```

Comment: I'm trying to get some data that I can't get through the API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is because headers needs to be a dict, not a list inside a dict:

```
  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',

                          'Galaxy-Ajax': 'true',
                          'Origin': 'https://analytics.google.com',
                          'Referer': 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr&pli=1',
                          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36',
                          },
```

That  will fix your current issue but you will get a 411 as you need to specify the content-length also, if you add what you want to pull from I will be able to show you how. You can see the output below:

```
2016-03-29 14:02:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr> from <GET https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?hl=fr&checkedDomains=youtube&pstMsg=0&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&service=analytics&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F%3Fhl%3Dfr&gidl=CAA>
2016-03-29 14:02:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo)
Login Successful!!
2016-03-29 14:02:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (411) <POST https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/getPage?id=trafficsources-all-traffic&ds=a5425w87291514p94531107&hl=fr&authuser=0> (referer: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=fr&pli=1)
2016-03-29 14:02:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <411 https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/getPage?id=trafficsources-all-traffic&ds=a5425w87291514p94531107&hl=fr&authuser=0>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I owe you a beer! I changed the http request headers and It finally worked.

Comment: @gerardbaste, no prob, glad you got it sorted, happy analysing.